# PHP - Multiple inserts using PDO and Json Array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I'm encountering a problem, I'm using PHP to insert and update data to a MySQL database. I send a JSON array from my app to this web service and then I need to insert this data into one table and update it on another table, the update part is working great but the insert part which I did exactly the same way it is not working, sometimes inserts only one object from the array and sometimes it doesn't add any.

can you guys help me? Thanks!!! Here's the code:

```
<?php

include "conexaoPDO.php";

$reserva_dados = $_POST['reserva_dados'];

$array = json_decode($reserva_dados, true);

foreach ($array as $row)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO reservas (id_reserva, id_sala, data_inicial, horario_inicial, data_final, horario_final, nome_processo, nome_consultor) VALUES ('".$row["id_reserva"]."', '".$row["id_sala"]."', '".$row["dia"]."', '".$row["horario"]."', '".$row["dia"]."', '".$row["horario"]."', '".$row["nome_processo"]."', '".$row["nome_consultor"]."')";

    $stmt = $PDO->query($sql);
}

foreach ($array as $row)
{
    $sql2 = "UPDATE calendario set status= '".$row["status"]."', id_reserva= '".$row["id_reserva"]."', nome_processo= '".$row["nome_processo"]."', nome_consultor= '".$row["nome_consultor"]."' WHERE id_sala= '".$row["id_sala"]."'  AND dia= '".$row["dia"]."' AND horario= '".$row["horario"]."'";

    $stmt = $PDO->query($sql2);
}
```

Regards,

Comment: `id_reserva` column is a primary key?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! It's not just about security. If any of the data contains a single quote or ends with a backslash, your query would break.

Comment: No, there are no primary keys

Comment: You should also add some proper [error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) to see if a query failed and why. Have you checked the servers error log?

Comment: Hi Magnus, I'm controlling the input from the app end, anyways is a "closed door" application, it won't open to public use.

Comment: Like my comment says, it's not all about security. If you pass data directly into the database without either escaping it or using prepared statements (preferred), the query can break if it contains some specific characters. Do some proper debugging to see if you get some error in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statements like these to avoid SQLInjection.
I'd try to rename your variables in order to be able to be more perceptive. You need to check how many values there is in the `$array` and why it's failing inserting (is there any errors?) You can use a `try catch` to catch any insertion errors.

Beware you are executing 1 query per foreach result, meaning eventually, the more data you have the slower it will be to insert. Try to build all the necessary records into 1 query (1 foreach to write the `$data` array with values).

```
include "conexaoPDO.php";
$reserva_dados = $_POST['reserva_dados'];
$array = json_decode($reserva_dados, true);

foreach ($array as $row)
{
    $data = [
    'id_reserva' => $row["id_reserva"],
    'id_sala' => $row["id_sala"],
    'data_inicial' => $row["dia"],
    'horario_inicial' => $row["horario"],
    'data_final' => $row["dia"],
    'horario_final' => $row["horario"],
    'nome_processo' => $row["nome_processo"],
    'nome_consultor' => $row["nome_consultor"]
    ];
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO reservas (id_reserva, id_sala, data_inicial, horario_inicial, data_final, horario_final, nome_processo, nome_consultor) VALUES (:id_reserva, :id_sala, :data_inicial, :horario_inicial, :data_final, :horario_final, :nome_processo, :nome_consultor)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
```

Comment: I agree that they should use prepared statements but currently, we have no idea if this even is the OP's current issue. IMHO, we should wait to give any answers until the OP has done some proper debugging and given us more to go on.

Comment: Hi abr and Magnus, thanks for the help! My problem other than the security is that the insert statement doesn't seem to work the same way the update does. I'm very new to php, started learning two weeks ago, so honestly I don't even know how to debug because I call the php file from the app and I don't know where would appear the message from the debug.

Comment: @victorracy you can use an application called POSTMAN and emulate an HTTP request (POST) in order to test things out. You can use "var_dump()" or "print_r()" followed by an "exit". Ignore what I said about trycatch, at least until you've learned more about php, I don't want you to get spoiled and bypass errors :P

Comment: @abr In postman how do I select the name of the json file I'm sending? like in my case it needs to be "reserva_dados" so the php identifies it.

Comment: select multi-form data as body type of the request, the url should be the url you are accessing. As for the body, your php file is expecting an array so the name of the values should be reserva_dados[0]['id_reserva'] and the corresponding value (and build the array you want to test out) Check this example https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlrcu.png

Comment: Thanks! I manage to try it out, so the problem is that I get a 500 internal server error when I try to insert the info. Do you know how I can get more details on why this is happening like some code to track the error in php?

Comment: 500 means it's an server-side error (meaning an error is ocorring in your php file). It can be a series of errors (empty variables that the table of the database requires it to be not null, missing variables, variable type (int vs string) missmatch). You need to find more information about your error, try using a trycatch or add this to the top of your file   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);